# MySQL: IN clause for dates BETWEEN a start and end date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have list of dates in the format `YYYY-MM`, and I have a table full of records with a `starts_at` and `ends_at` column.

I want to find all records for which any given date in the passed-in list is within the `starts_at` and `ends_at` range.

So, given `2011-01, 2011-05, 2011-10`, I want:

```
| id | starts_at           | ends_at             | title                             |
| 3  | 2010-12-05 00:00:00 | 2011-02-02 00:00:00 | something cool                    |
| 4  | 2011-03-14 00:00:00 | 2011-05-01 00:00:00 | something else really cool        |
| 5  | 2011-10-31 00:00:00 | 2012-12-23 00:00:00 | argh! end of the world! not cool! |
```

... while these records would be omitted:

```
| id | starts_at           | ends_at             | title                             |
| 6  | 2010-10-05 00:00:00 | 2010-12-02 00:00:00 | something uncool                  |
| 7  | 2011-03-14 00:00:00 | 2011-04-31 00:00:00 | something else really uncool      |
| 8  | 2011-12-23 00:00:00 | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 | yay! we're still alive! cool!     |
```

How would I write this `WHERE` condition in SQL?

---

**Clarification**: I'm looking for a solution in pure SQL (I'm working with a stored procedure, so dynamic injection through some other language like PHP isn't really possible, so far as I know), and the list of dates is being passed in to the query as a `string` (HTML form input). I would love to break it down into sequential `BETWEEN` statements if I could do that programmatically in SQL, but I've no clue how to do that.

Basically, I need a way to express the following logic in pure SQL:

```
$months = explode(',', '2011-01,2011-05,2011-10');
$q = "SELECT records.* FROM records WHERE";
foreach($months as $month) {
  $q .= " '$month' BETWEEN records.starts_at AND records.ends_at OR";
}
$q = substr($q, 0, -3) . ';';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, starts_at, ends_at, title
FROM yourtable
WHERE '2011-01-01' BETWEEN starts_at AND ends_at
OR    '2011-05-01' BETWEEN starts_at AND ends_at
OR    '2011-10-01' BETWEEN starts_at AND ends_at
```

Comment: Not quite what I was after... the list of dates is a string passed in to the query, not as individual variables... something like this: `WHERE record.an_imaginary_date_field IN (2011-01, 2011-05, 2011-10)`... unless there's a way in SQL to parse out that string to get separate values?

Comment: @neezer: It's probably best to parse it to separate values at the client.

Comment: @MarkByers There's no SQL-only way to accomplish this? I'm working with a stored procedure here that's rather complex. There's no way to pass an array of months to the stored procedure in place of the imploded string, then loop over that array to do the `BETWEEN` statements listed above?

Comment: @MarkByers, did you try this?  For me this only works if `starts_at` and `ends_at` are strings.  If they are instead DATETIME or TIMESTAMP columns, MySQL will NULLify the string _YYYY-MM_ value (ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE), and so the BETWEEN will always be false.

Comment: @pilcrow: He said they were strings in his question.

Comment: @MarkByers, I only see that the OP said that the search criteria were passed in as strings, not the columns.

Comment: @neezer: You will either need to split the string and join, or use dynamic SQL to create the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate your month specifiers into start of month and end of month (`som` and `eom` below) and do it yourself:

```
SET sql_mode='ansi';

SELECT neezer.*
  FROM neezer
  JOIN (SELECT m || '-01' AS som,
               DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(m || '-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 SECOND) AS eom
          FROM (SELECT '2011-01' AS m
                 UNION ALL
                SELECT '2011-05'
                 UNION ALL
                SELECT '2011-10') d) month_intervals
       ON som <= ends_at AND eom >= starts_at;
```

So, we convert each `'2011-01'` into a paired DATE and DATETIME, and then compute the overlap.  (The reason we convert `eom` into 'YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59' is so that `'2011-01'` matches an interval that `starts_at` '2011-01-01 01:00:00' (otherwise `eom` would be coerced to 00:00:00 on the initial day and not match our `starts_at`).

Comment: Hmm, is there any reason why you don't use `BETWEEN` here? Also, is there anyway to do this programmatically in pure SQL? See my edit above for what I mean...

Comment: @neezer, I'm assuming `starts_at` and `ends_at` are temporal types, not strings.  See my comment on MarkByer's answer.  As to your "pure SQL" question, no.  However, a stored procedure of your own design might be able to split the string and spit out the right query or populate a temporary table with the date ranges you care about.