# Syntax error of ''?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I can't seem to figure out where this is coming from... MySQL give me a syntax error of an empty quote and gives me a line number that doesn't seem to be wrong at all. Worse still, deleting the loop the line number points to still gives me the same error, just with a different line number.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 13: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '' at line 39

Talk about unhelpful feedback from MySQL!

The code in question is a stored function, and I ran into this when trying to apply [the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023917/mysql-temporary-table-in-stored-functions). The updated code is [available here](https://gist.github.com/1342136).

---

EDIT: @MarkByers, here's the function reduced as low as I could get it while still triggering the error:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS months_within_range;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION months_within_range(starts_at DATE, ends_at DATE, filter_range VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS TINYINT
BEGIN
  SET @matches = 1;
  IF @matches >= 1 THEN RETURN 1;
  ELSE RETURN 0;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. Oh man, 149 of them... :(

Comment: Can you try reducing the stored procedure so that it contains the smallest number of lines possible, but still produces the error?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Old habits die hard. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the END IF

```
 IF @matches >= 1 THEN RETURN 1;
 ELSE RETURN 0;
 END IF;
```

And the reason `RETURN IF(@matches >= 1, 1, 0);` works is because this is the `IF function`, which is different from the `IF statement`

Comment: Of course it's something simple. Thanks... been looking at this stuff for waaaaaay too long.